# Is Black Museum trying to suggest there is a chronological order in Black Mirror?

Tags: reference, chronology, black-mirror

In *Black Mirror* S04E06 *Black Museum*, we got mention of so many previous episodes that it seems like it is clearly suggesting that it exists in the same universe. It mentions cookies from *White Christmas* and cloud storage from *USS Callister*. Even Tommy's lollipop made an appearance, suggesting it takes place after that episode; it also mentions that cookies are old technology.

Is this a deliberate attempt to address fan theories about the whole show existing in the same universe, or just more extended Easter eggs? This episode does set a bit of chronology. Did any of the official persons address it?

Comment: In the episode White Christmas, when watching news in TV, you can see in on other channels the talent show from season 1 and other references to previous episodes. Also - people in White Christmas have the same eye implants as in S01E03.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it seems that Black Museum proves fan theories that the whole show exists in the same universe true.

From [the interview with Charlie Brooker with Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/black-mirror/news/a845932/black-mirror-shared-universe-confirmed-easter-eggs/),

> In our exclusive interview, Brooker reveals the surprising reason why the Easter eggs started, and how upcoming episode 'Black Museum' connects Black Mirror's disparate strands.
>
> "It does actually now seem to imply that it is all a shared universe," he reveals.

Above article contains a video of full interview.

From [Heavy article](https://heavy.com/entertainment/2017/12/black-museum-explained-black-mirror-last-episode-six-meaning/),

> Brooker said: “It used to be that we would refer to other things partly because it was convenient… **As time goes on we’ve put more and more of these nods to other stories in, and certainly this season for the first time … the first very explicitly, one of our episodes, Black Museum, has got very specific references to previous stories we’ve done, and it is sort of filling in a bit of backstory there.** You don’t need to have seen those to watch the show… **But it does actually sort of now seem to imply that is actually all a shared universe, which was the opposite of the answer I used to give to this question.”**